# Google Chrome blank page / Cannot open anything

Tags: chrome

As of today I cannot use Google's Browser Chrome anymore.
Whenever I open the Browser I get a blank screen of everything (meaning any site, any internal site (even file://).

I have tried to reinstall the browser with
`apt-get install google-chrome-stable --reinstall`

And also to start the browser in incognito mode (`--incognito`) and with all extensions disabled (`--disable-extensions`)

Installed Version:

```
pascal@trouble:~$ google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 38.0.2125.111
```

This is what it looks like (on every page):

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this, perhaps?

Comment: I don't use Linux so i don't know where the files are but trying removing Program Files and Preference files, and clear cookies and cache. However if `file://` shows blank I'm not sure clearing cookies and cache will work.

Comment: @DisplayName I cannot go into settings as they come blank, too. (I could clear the cache from command line if thats possible of even hard-delete it with using rm -rf - but that really is my last hope only)

Comment: I've had similar problems due to video driver problems, typically when the X driver version and the underlying kernel driver were out of synch. Have you updated any X or kernel package recently? Did you try rebooting?

Comment: @Gilles The reboot fixed the problem.